# java.util.NoSuchElementException when iterating the List

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to iterate the list and check the max value to get that object.

```
Class One{
//properties
private int id;
private boolean isInsurance;
private List<FamilyAge> familyAge;
}
class FamilyAge{
private Long aId;
private String holder1;
private String holder2;
..
}
```

Above are the sample class objects iterating below.

```
    List<One> myList1 = getAllRequiredData();
        myList1.stream().forEach(list1 -> list1.getFamilyAge().stream()
                                     .max(Comparator.comparing(FamilyAge::getAId)).get()); 
         //java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
```

I want to filter or get only one object of FamilyAge which has max of aId. With the above iteration logic it is throwing java.util.NoSuchElementException.

Comment: That means one of the lists are empty.

Answer (score 2):

`max` is returning an `Optional`. Calling `get` on an optional is usually a bad idea. `Optional` is used to wrap values that could potentially be `null` and if `get` would return null it throws a `NoSuchElementException` instead. A better solution could look something like this

```
myList1.stream()
    .forEach(list1 -> list1.getFamilyAge().stream()                    
        .max(Comparator.comparing(FamilyAge::getAId))
            .ifPresent(familyAge -> /* do something with family age*/));
```

As the name suggests ifPresent is only executed if the object is present.

Answer (score 1):

Never use `get()` unless you’re *sure* there will be something in the stream.

either code:

```
.max(…).orElse(null)
```

Or code:

```
.max(…).ifPresent(x -> /* do something */)
```

To handle the case where there isn’t a max because the stream is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Don't shove a lambda on one gigantic line; it is now extremely hard to figure out where the exception is trying to point your attention to. Add some newlines to that thing! You're not iterating the list, you're calling forEach.

The `.get()` call at the very end is the likely culprit: Your stream operation ended up with 0 things; asking the 'maximum' out of 0 things results in no value.
One of the `One` instances has a zero-length `familyAge`.